# Is there a way to pass Kotlin's String::startsWith to a method that takes Java's String::startsWith?

Tags: java, kotlin

I've got a Java method that takes an argument of the type

```
interface Function2<TP1, TP2, TR> {
  TR apply(TP1 p1, TP2 p2)
}
```

and a Java method like so

```
boolean containsMatch(String[] sa, String s, Function2<String, String, boolean> compare) {
  ...
}
```

In my Java code, I can call `containsMatch` and pass `String::startsWith` as the `compare` parameter.

When I try to call from my Kotlin code, there doesn't appear to be any overload of `String::startsWith` that only takes one argument. Is there any way to get the compiler to use one of the overloads with a default parameter value, or do I need to pass in a lambda or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin functions with default parameters cannot be called from Java without all arguments specified, since Java does not know the concept of default parameters. There is the `@JvmOverloads` annotation which creates multiple overloads to emulate the Kotlin behavior in Java.

Regarding your question, the same applies to method references, which is why you can't simply pass `String::startsWith`. You can however pass a closure `{ a, b -> a.startsWith(b) }`

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass a Kotlin lambda to it and it should work fine...

```
containsMatch(arrayOf("A", "B", "C"), "A", { a, b -> a.startsWith(b) })

// Or this, which is a more idiomatc way of typing it.
containsMatch(arrayOf("A", "B", "C"), "A") { a, b -> a.startsWith(b) }
```